# What is the proper syntax to access attribute (public_ip) of a resource (aws_instance) with count from another resource (null_resource)

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and this issue is perhaps addressed earlier. Unfortunately, I am not able to find one.

***Question***: What is the proper syntax to access attribute (public_ip) of a resource (aws_instance) with count from another resource (null_resource).

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12, < 0.13"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

  # Allow any 2.x version of the AWS provider
  version = "~> 2.0"
}

variable instances {
  default = 2
}

variable username {
}

variable password {
}

resource "null_resource" "test-null" {
  count         = var.instances
  
  provisioner "file" {
    content     = "foo"
    destination = "~/bar"

    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      host = aws_instance.test-instance.*.public_ip
      user = var.username
      password = var.password
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "test-instance" {
  count         = var.instances
  
  ami           = "ami-c50e37be"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  
}
```

Applying this gives the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type: Inappropriate value for attribute "host": string required.
```

Based on my understanding, it is because "aws_instance.test-instance.*.public_ip" gives list of public_ip, not specific element.

I tried many variations, but none works.

Please suggest the right syntax in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it should have been:

**host = aws_instance.test-instance.*.public_ip[count.index]**

Please let me know if there are better alternatives.

Also, I am not sure I posted it on the right forum. If not, please suggest alternative.

Thank You!